# Remove useless zero digits from decimals in PHP

Tags: php, numbers, decimal

I'm trying to find a fast way to remove `zero decimals` from number values like this:

```
echo cleanNumber('125.00');
// 125

echo cleanNumber('966.70');
// 966.7

echo cleanNumber(844.011);
// 844.011
```

Does exists some optimized way to do that?

Comment: As your values are actually strings, why not simply use rtrim() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php - with a '0.' as the second argument

Comment: Sorry, I've been not fully clear, they are not always strings, i fix the question.

Comment: @Mark Baker: that is a bad approach as number 120 will be trimmed to 12

Comment: @machineaddict - it would if, and only if, the string values didn't have a decimal point..... all those cited by the OP have a decimal point.

Comment: Then you should add a bold notice in your answer, that it only works if there are decimals.

Comment: In maths "useless zeros" are called insignificant figures [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Identifying_significant_figures)

Comment: @David Except these aren't insignificant figures. In math, trailing 0s after the decimal *are* significant.

Answer (score 411, accepted):

`$num + 0` does the trick.

```
echo 125.00 + 0; // 125
echo '125.00' + 0; // 125
echo 966.70 + 0; // 966.7
```

Internally, this is equivalent to casting to float with `(float)$num` or `floatval($num)` but I find it simpler.

Comment: i think this is a dirty trick. i would not prefer it because the code doesn't tell about his behavior like `floatval()` is doing it.

Comment: @ESCOBAR `floatval`'s behavior is returning a float. I would argue using it as a decimals formatter is not very obvious or clean either.

Comment: This is a very unclear. Our team just encountered this in our code, and it had 3 developers puzzled for some time. I think [Mark's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26980002/2070622) is a better alternative. It is longer, but its intent is clear.

Comment: @jfbalanc `//COMMENT`

Comment: @jfbalanc If you put it as the single line function called trimTrailingZeroes (like Mark's answer) that would probably make it more clear.

Comment: @ESCOBAR Not really, it's an officially suggested method for typecasting... search "type juggling" on php.net

Comment: be aware: ```125.00 + 0 !== 125``` but ```125.00 + 0 === 125.0```.

Comment: The funny answer, but perfectly functional.

Comment: @lafor i disagree. It is not used as a decimals formatter, since you can not speficy the amout of decimal places you want returned.
Instead, what it does is give you the numeric value of it, wich implicitly does not have trailing zeroes. Trailing decimal zeroes carry no information and are therefore mathematically non existing.  To have them or not is a question that only exists in the realm of strings.

Comment: What if I have formatted number 954,543.00 and I want it formatted but without those zeros?

Comment: @pgood that number will be divided over 1000, so, this marked answer isn't right except for numbers < 1000.

Comment: `(float)$num`  it is than, clear and simple

Answer (score 130):

you could just use the `floatval` function

```
echo floatval('125.00');
// 125

echo floatval('966.70');
// 966.7

echo floatval('844.011');
// 844.011
```

Comment: it fails when the thousand separator is a dot and decimal mark is a comma.

Comment: This is not accurate. floatval('125.00') will return 125.0, not 125 in PHP 8.1.

Comment: I'm getting 3000 for 3000.24 in PHP 7.4

Comment: It's Deprecated.

Answer (score 31):

This is what I use:

```
function TrimTrailingZeroes($nbr) {
    return strpos($nbr,'.')!==false ? rtrim(rtrim($nbr,'0'),'.') : $nbr;
}
```

N.B. This assumes `.` is the decimal separator. It has the advantage that it will work on arbitrarily large (or small) numbers since there is no float cast. It also won't turn numbers into scientific notation (e.g. 1.0E-17).

Comment: this is not a safe solution, what if the price is not decimal?for example if developer multiply the price with an integer then we have an integer

Comment: @alex This function works on integers, floats and strings.

Comment: Perfect solution as helper for bcmath

Comment: This is the only answer that works if the input might contain a comma thousands separator (which fail to cast to float). If the input comes from `number_format()`, which always includes a decimal separator if a decimal value is provided, the code can be simplified to, e.g.: `$output = rtrim(rtrim(number_format($input, 10), '0'), '.')`

Comment: Works well to parse result after doing `number_format()`. Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

If you want to remove the zero digits just before to display on the page or template.

You can use the [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function

```
sprintf('%g','125.00');
// 125

‌‌sprintf('%g','966.70');
// 966.7

‌‌‌‌sprintf('%g',844.011);
// 844.011
```

Comment: Thanks I loved this answer. This is very helpful for me.

Comment: How about to change the decimal separator and thousand separator?

Comment: @RayCoder **sprintf** doesn't have options for adding thousand separators, you can try : 
`sprintf('%s', number_format(2699, 0, '.', ','))`

Answer (score 20):

Simply adding `+` to your string variable will cause typecast to **(float)** and removes zeros:

```
var_dump(+'125.00');     // double(125)
var_dump(+'966.70');     // double(966.7)
var_dump(+'844.011');    // double(844.011)
var_dump(+'844.011asdf');// double(844.011)
```

Answer (score 19):

For everyone coming to this site having the same problem with commata instead, change:

```
$num = number_format($value, 1, ',', '');
```

to:

```
$num = str_replace(',0', '', number_format($value, 1, ',', '')); // e.g. 100,0 becomes 100
```

If there are **two zeros** to be removed, then change to:

```
$num = str_replace(',00', '', number_format($value, 2, ',', '')); // e.g. 100,00 becomes 100
```

More here: [PHP number: decimal point visible only if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4113200/1066234)

Answer (score 10):

You should cast your numbers as floats, which will do this for you.

```
$string = "42.422005000000000000000000000000";
echo (float)$string;
```

Output of this will be what you are looking for.

> 42.422005

Comment: Float casting might also corrupt your number. e.g. `(float)'0.1234567890124567890123456789'` becomes `0.12345678901246`.

Answer (score 8):

Typecast to a `float`.

```
$int = 4.324000;
$int = (float) $int;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$x = '100.10'; 
$x = preg_replace("/\.?0*$/",'',$x); 
echo $x;
```

There is nothing that can't be fixed with a simple regex ;)

http://xkcd.com/208/

Comment: Strips off significant `0`s such as in `"100"`. Also fails to strip `0`s off `"100.010"`.

Comment: Everybody stand back!
`$x = preg_replace("/(\.0*$)|((?<=\.\d*)0+$)/",'',$x);`

Answer (score 3):

Example 1

```
$value =81,500.00;
{{rtrim(rtrim(number_format($value,2),0),'.')}}
```

> **output**
>
> 81,500

Example 2

```
$value=110,763.14;
{{rtrim(rtrim(number_format($value,2),0),'.')}}
```

> **output**
>
> 110,763.14

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Due to this question is old. First, I'm sorry about this.

The question is about number xxx.xx but in case that it is x,xxx.xxxxx or difference decimal separator such as xxxx,xxxx this can be harder to find and remove zero digits from decimal value.

```php
/**
 * Remove zero digits (include zero trails - 123.450, 123.000) from decimal value.
 * 
 * @param string|int|float $number The number can be any format, any where use in the world such as 123, 1,234.56, 1234.56789, 12.345,67, -98,765.43
 * @param string The decimal separator. You have to set this parameter to exactly what it is. For example: in Europe it is mostly use "," instead of ".".
 * @return string Return removed zero digits from decimal value. Only return as string!
 */
function removeZeroDigitsFromDecimal($number, $decimal_sep = '.')
{
    $explode_num = explode($decimal_sep, $number);
    if (is_countable($explode_num) && count($explode_num) > 1) {
        // if exploded number is more than 1 (Example: explode with . for nnnn.nnn is 2)
        // replace `is_countable()` with `is_array()` if you are using PHP older than 7.3.
        $explode_num[count($explode_num)-1] = preg_replace('/(0+)$/', '', $explode_num[count($explode_num)-1]);
        if ($explode_num[count($explode_num)-1] === '') {
            // if the decimal value is now empty. 
            // unset it to prevent nnn. without any number.
            unset($explode_num[count($explode_num)-1]);
        }
        $number = implode($decimal_sep, $explode_num);
    }
    unset($explode_num);
    return (string) $number;
}
```

And here is the code for test.

```php
$tests = [
    1234 => 1234,
    -1234 => -1234,
    '12,345.67890' => '12,345.6789',
    '-12,345,678.901234' => '-12,345,678.901234',
    '12345.000000' => '12345',
    '-12345.000000' => '-12345',
    '12,345.000000' => '12,345',
    '-12,345.000000000' => '-12,345',
];
foreach ($tests as $number => $assert) {
    $result = removeZeroDigitsFromDecimal($number);
    assert($result === (string) $assert, new \Exception($result . ' (' . gettype($result) . ') is not matched ' . $assert . ' (' . gettype($assert) . ')'));
    echo $number . ' =&gt; ' . (string) $assert . '<br>';
}

echo '<hr>' . PHP_EOL;

$tests = [
    1234 => 1234,
    -1234 => -1234,
    '12.345,67890' => '12.345,6789',
    '-12.345.678,901234' => '-12.345.678,901234',
    '12345,000000' => '12345',
    '-12345,000000' => '-12345',
    '-12.345,000000000' => '-12.345',
    '-12.345,000000,000' => '-12.345,000000',// this is correct assertion. Weird ,000000,000 but only last 000 will be removed.
];
foreach ($tests as $number => $assert) {
    $result = removeZeroDigitsFromDecimal($number, ',');
    assert($result === (string) $assert, new \Exception($result . ' (' . gettype($result) . ') is not matched ' . $assert . ' (' . gettype($assert) . ')'));
    echo $number . ' =&gt; ' . (string) $assert . '<br>';
}
```

All tests should be pass and no errors.

Why `'-12.345,000000,000'` will be `'-12.345,000000'` not `'-12.345'`?
Because this function is for remove zero digits (include zero trails) from decimal value. It is not validation for the correct number format. That should be another function.

Why always return as string?
Because it is better to use in calculation with `bcxxx` functions, or use with big number.

Comment: You are not removing 0 here? Line 4: '12,345.67890',// 12,345.67890

Comment: @Siwei Updated my function and tests. It is now able to remove `.0000` and change `.123450` to be `.12345`.
However, I don't think it should remove incorrect number format like `123.456.789` because it should be in validation function, or Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, especially in case of monetary amounts, you want to remove the zeros only if they are 2, you don't want to print `€ 2.1` instead of `€ 2.10`.

An implementation could be:

```
function formatAmount(string|float|int $value, int $decimals = 2): string
{
    if (floatval(intval($value)) === floatval($value)) {
        // The number is an integer. Remove all the decimals
        return (string)intval($value);
    }

    return number_format($value, $decimals);
}
```

Examples of expected outputs:

```
0.1000 => 0.10
20.000 => 20
1.25 => 1.25
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats my small solution...
Can included to a class and set vars

private $dsepparator = '.'; // decimals
private $tsepparator= ','; // thousand

That can be set by constructor and change to users lang.

```
class foo
{
    private $dsepparator;
    private $tsepparator;

    function __construct(){
        $langDatas = ['en' => ['dsepparator' => '.', 'tsepparator' => ','], 'de' => ['dsepparator' => ',', 'tsepparator' => '.']];
        $usersLang = 'de'; // set iso code of lang from user
        $this->dsepparator = $langDatas[$usersLang]['dsepparator'];
        $this->tsepparator = $langDatas[$usersLang]['tsepparator'];
    }

    public function numberOmat($amount, $decimals = 2, $hideByZero = false)
    {
        return ( $hideByZero === true AND ($amount-floor($amount)) <= 0 ) ? number_format($amount, 0, $this->dsepparator, $this->tsepparator) : number_format($amount, $decimals, $this->dsepparator, $this->tsepparator);
    }
    /*
     * $bar = new foo();
     * $bar->numberOmat('5.1234', 2, true); // returns: 5,12
     * $bar->numberOmat('5', 2); // returns: 5,00
     * $bar->numberOmat('5.00', 2, true); // returns: 5
     */

}
```

Comment: So i have build a sample class with little samples. Better? =)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 15.00;
$str2 = 14.70;
echo rtrim(rtrim(strval($str), "0"), "."); //15
echo rtrim(rtrim(strval($str2), "0"), "."); //14.7
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution is the best:

```
public function priceFormat(float $price): string
{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/14531760/5884988
    $price = $price + 0;
    $split = explode('.', $price);
    return number_format($price, isset($split[1]) ? strlen($split[1]) : 2, ',', '.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is much simpler

```php
if(floor($num) == $num) {
    echo number_format($num);
} else {
    echo $num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```php
rtrim(number_format($coin->current_price,6),'0.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Complicated way but works:

```
$num = '125.0100';
$index = $num[strlen($num)-1];
$i = strlen($num)-1;
while($index == '0') {
   if ($num[$i] == '0') {
     $num[$i] = '';
     $i--;
   }

   $index = $num[$i];
}

//remove dot if no numbers exist after dot
$explode = explode('.', $num);
if (isset($explode[1]) && intval($explode[1]) <= 0) {
   $num = intval($explode[0]);
}

echo $num; //125.01
```

the solutions above are the optimal way but in case you want to have your own you could use this. What this algorithm does it starts at the end of string and checks if its **0**, if it is it sets to empty string and then goes to the next character from back untill the last character is **> 0**

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = preg_replace('~\.0+$~','',$value);
```

Comment: It would improve the quality of your answer if you provided an explanation of what your code does and how it will solve the original question.

Comment: @Nikhil Gyan  I agree this answer isn't great.  Feel free to ote down.  However, I at least don't think it is bad enough for very low quality flag

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
print (floatval)(number_format( $Value), 2 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. 
I want to keep ability to add thousands separator

```
    $precision = 5;    
    $number = round($number, $precision);
    $decimals = strlen(substr(strrchr($number, '.'), 1));
    return number_format($number, $precision, '.', ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple one line function using rtrim, save separator and decimal point :

```
function myFormat($num,$dec)
 {
 return rtrim(rtrim(number_format($num,$dec),'0'),'.');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and accurate!

```
function cleanNumber($num){
    $explode = explode('.', $num);
    $count   = strlen(rtrim($explode[1],'0'));
    return bcmul("$num",'1', $count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple code:

```
define('DECIMAL_SEPARATOR', ','); //To prove that it works with different separators than "."

$input = "50,00";

$number = rtrim($input, '0');                // 50,00 --> 50,
$number = rtrim($number, DECIMAL_SEPARATOR); // 50,   --> 50

echo $number;
```

Seems a bit too easy to be the *really* correct solution, but it works just fine for me. You should do some tests with the inputs you'll be getting before using this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the amount is a string with 2 decimal places, then you can use:

```
protected function removeZerosDecimals(string $money): string
{
    $formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);

    $uselessDecimals = sprintf(
        '%s00',
        $formatter->getSymbol(NumberFormatter::DECIMAL_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL)
    );
    if (!str_ends_with($money, $uselessDecimals)) {
        return $money;
    }

    $len = mb_strlen($money);
    return mb_substr($money, 0, $len - mb_strlen($uselessDecimals));
}
```

That will work as expected for ?any? currency, like `$500.00` and `R$ 500,00`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeZerosAfterDecimals($number) {

$number = trim($number);

if($number <= 0 || empty($number)) {
    return $number;
}

$ary = explode('.', $number);

if(count($ary) <= 1) {
    return $number;
}

$reverseAry = array_reverse($ary);

$endSearch = false;
$newNumber = [];

for($i=0; $i<count($reverseAry); $i++) {
    if($reverseAry[$i] != 0 && $endSearch === false) {
        $newNumber[] = $reverseAry[$i];
        $endSearch = true;
    } else if ($endSearch === true) {
        $newNumber[] = $reverseAry[$i];
    }
}


return implode('.',array_reverse($newNumber));
```

}

//output: 10.0.1.0 => 10.0.1

//output: 10.0.1 => 10.0.1

//output: 10.1.2 => 10.1.2

//output: 10.0.0 => 10

This function will only remove the trailing zero decimals

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use [round()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.round.php)

```
function cleanNumber( $amount = 0, $min = 0, $max = 8 )
    {
        $amount = round($amount, $max);
        $expl = explode('.', $amount);
        
        if (!isset($expl[1]) || $expl[1] < $min){
            $amount = sprintf('%02.'.$min.'F', $amount);
        }
        return $amount;
    }
    
    
echo cleanNumber('125.00').'   ';

echo cleanNumber('966.70').'   ';

echo cleanNumber(844.011).'   ';

echo cleanNumber(844.00000000000000000000000000000000, 2, 8).'   ';

echo cleanNumber(844.77777777777777777777777777777777, 2, 8).'   ';
```

[PHP Sandbox](https://onlinephp.io/c/d39d5)

Answer (score -1):

### This Code will remove zero after point and will return only two decimal digits.

$number=1200.0000;
str_replace('.00', '',number_format($number, 2, '.', ''));

**Output will be: 1200**

Comment: This actually made sense because sometimes (monetary amounts) you want to remove the zeros if they are 2, you don't want to print `€ 2.1` instead of `€ 2.10`

Answer (score -1):

Ultimate Solution: The only safe way is to use regex:

```
echo preg_replace("/\.?0+$/", "", 3.0); // 3
echo preg_replace("/\d+\.?\d*(\.?0+)/", "", 3.0); // 3
```

it will work for any case

Answer (score -1):

**ADVICE**: the [marked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14531760/1030070) works ONLY for numbers below 1000 or if the value greater than 1000 doesn't have a number format like '#,###.##'.

A better approximation is like the following (the fraction algo at https://gist.github.com/graceman9/2f912b28e6c8aecf4421):

```
$value = 125.00; // or 1250.00
$whole = floor($value); // 125
$fraction = round($value - $whole, 2);
$result = number_format($value, $fraction >= 0.01 ? 2 : 0, ",", "."); // Or whatever number format that you need
```

Comment: The marked answer works for numbers of any value. It doesn't work for string representation of numbers containing thousands separator(s) (which you assume is `,` but can be `'` or a half-space or a bunch of other characters). Neither does your answer, BTW. You can't `floor` or subtract from a string in a `#,###.##` format. Also, OP wanted to drop insignificant zeroes from the decimal part, not round it to 2 digits. `0.23600` should become `0.236`, not `0.24`.