# Efficient way of removing extraneous zeros from prices?

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have prices stored to five decimal places of precision, such as:

```
1.95000
2.25000
0.01150
2.10000
2.00000
```

When displaying prices, I'd like to show the standard `$X.XX` format if the rest of the digits are just zero, but if there are significant digits then I don't want to cut them out (so I can't simply use `number_format()`).

As an example, the above prices should display as:

```
1.95
2.25
0.0115
2.10
2.00
```

This process has to be done on hundreds of prices per page. What's an efficient way of formatting numbers in this manner?

Comment: Try this if useful: echo (float)$pricestring;

Comment: @Chandresh Doesn't keep two decimal places of precision when the digits to the right of the decimal point are `0`'s. Ex `echo (float)'2.00'` results in `2`.

Comment: Have you referred this one?-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531679/remove-useless-zero-digits-from-decimals-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of ugly but it does the job:

```
function formatPrice($price) {
    $out = (float)$price; // Trim off right-hand 0's
    $out = "$out"; // Typecast back to string
    if ((strlen($out) - strpos($out, '.')) <= 2) { // Test for string length after decimal point
        $out = number_format($out, 2); // Format back with 0's
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Testing it now... [Works!](http://codepad.org/r8LuU3Er)

Here's a one-liner function from my other comment thanks to @FuzzyTree's answer:

```
function formatPrice($price) {
    return substr($price, 0, strpos($price, '.') + 3) . rtrim(substr($price, strpos($price, '.') + 3), '0');
}
```

Comment: Would you want to update your answer with the comment you left on the other answer? Your one-liner works, although I had to change the `+ 2` to `+ 3`.

Comment: @Nate Sure, done! However I had already [added my comment to that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27309026/5)

Answer (score 3):

This uses a regex to match everything before the trailing 0s

```
$i = "$1.00";
$pattern = '/\$(\d+)\.(\d\d)(0*)/';
$replacement = '\$$1.$2';
print preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$i);
```

Another way using `rtrim` on everything after the first 2 digits right of the decimal

```
$pos = strpos($i, '.') + 3;
print substr($i, 0, $pos) . rtrim(substr($i, $pos), '0');
```

Comment: I almost started trying to write a regex for this, then thought to myself "no.. there has to be a better way!"

Comment: @Nate I don't think there is, since you're looking for two explicit parameters: round off 0's + preserve at least 2 decimal places. You either check each separately or regex. EDIT: Hot damn

Comment: How about `substr($i, 0, strpos($i, '.') + 2) . rtrim(substr($i, strpos($i, '.') + 2), '0')` for a one-liner? You could take the `strpos` into another variable though to lower execution time.

Comment: @sjagr agreed, that's a faster way