# Remove useless 0 after 3 digits and round after 6 digit

Tags: php, rounding

I use the `floatval()` function to remove useless `0`s, but I want to keep at least 3 significant numbers. Like if I have `0.1800000` I want to show `0.180` and if I have `1.8454214` I want to show `1.845421`. How can I do a round after 6 digits and remove useless `0`s after 3 digits?

```
$value = 1.80000;
$value = floatval(round($value,6));
echo $value;   //I get 1.8
```

Or if I have

```
$value = 1.84542146543;
$value = floatval(round($value,6));
echo $value;   //I get 1.845421
```

And this works fine, but not if I've got a lot of `0`s.

I always need minimum 3 decimal, but it can be more.

Comment: Per this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531679/remove-useless-zero-digits-from-decimals-in-php) you can do `$value + 0` to remove any unnecessary trailing 0s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of `floor` and `sprintf` to truncate the float to a string with 3 decimal places. Then use `max` to compare it with the rounded float. PHP will compare the values numerically, returning the first parameter (padded with zeros) if they are numerically the same, only returning the second value if it is numerically greater (ie there is a digit larger than 0 after the third decimal place).

```
$value = max(
    sprintf("%.3f", floor($value * pow(10, 3)) / pow(10, 3)),
    round($value, 6));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code

```
$value = 1.80000;
$value = floatval(round($value,6));
$valArr = explode('.', $value);
if(isset($valArr[1])){
    if(strlen($valArr[1]) < 3){
        $valArr[1] = str_pad($valArr[1], 3, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $value = $valArr[0].'.'.$valArr[1];
    }
    else{
        $value = floatval(round($value,6));
    }
}

echo $value;
```

It will work if you want to print the 0s in your web page.

Comment: It doesn't work when I have 12.1, it gives me 12.10 and I always need to put 3 decimals. It should be 12.100

Comment: @Samybel, Sorry for that. I have edited the answer. Please try now

Comment: you can use this echo round(1.80000,2);    // 1.800