# deleting zeros in a decimal number after the decimal point

Tags: php, number-formatting

Can anyone please suggest a way to delete all zeros after the decimal point.

I need the numbers to be changed as following:

```
 232.20 should be converted to 232.2
 232.00 should be converted to 232
 232.22 should be the same
```

does `number_format()` help in any way?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14531760/2968762

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove useless zero digits from decimals in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531679/remove-useless-zero-digits-from-decimals-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `floatval( your_value )`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `floatval()`:

```
echo floatval('12.00');
// 12

echo floatval('66.70');
// 66.7

echo floatval('44.011');
// 44.011
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a zero

```
echo 232.20 + 0; // 232.2
echo 232.00 + 0; // 232
echo 232.22 + 0; // 232.22
```

I have taken reference for the SO question [Remove useless zero digits from decimals in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531679/remove-useless-zero-digits-from-decimals-in-php)

Please have a look