# PHP how to keep the result in decimal format and remove unnecessary zero?

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
<?php

$number = 0.000010950000;
$number = number_format($number, 10, '.', '');
$number = $number + 0;

echo $number;
```

I'm expecting this as result :

```
0.00001095
```

but, by using `number_format` only, it will produce :

```
0.0000109500
```

and by adding `+ 0` to remove unnecessary zero, it will print the number into scientific format :

```
1.095E-5
```

how to keep the result in decimal format and remove unnecessary zero?

please note, length of number can be vary.

Comment: As an option, store as is, but use `rtrim($number, '0')` before output.

Comment: @MaratTanalin : I used rtrim before. but if you have number like 10.00, you will get 10. (with extra dot). any idea how to get 10 (without dot)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Remove Unnecessary Zero In Decimals Works, But Not With This Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56172607/php-remove-unnecessary-zero-in-decimals-works-but-not-with-this-number)

Comment: @MaratTanalin's comment perfectly fits the issue *as you have described it in your question*. If there are extra situations that need to be covered  (as described in your comment) please update  (**edit**) your question to clarify these additional circumstances. I have included a solution your comments in my answer to your question. Thank you.

Comment: @Andreas this is a useless duplicate. that question has no answers. And it's own dupe-trail goes back to a question whose answers do not fit this situation.

Comment: The thing is I wanted to show that the user has asked the same question in the past and didn't even answer what output he/she wanted

Comment: @Andreas that is a fair point but it is still not a  useful duplicate flag. Maybe one eventually for a moderator to tag as a repetative asking....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove useless zero digits from decimals in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531679/remove-useless-zero-digits-from-decimals-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments:

```
$number = 0.000010950000;
$number = number_format($number, 10, '.',''); // to avoid scientific notation of tiny decimals
$number = rtrim((string)$number,'0');
$number = rtrim((string)$number,'.');

echo $number;
```

What this does:

the first `rtrim` will clear the excess `0`, the second `rtrim` will clear any trailing `.` **after** the first `rtrim` is completed.

**Why not combine the `rtrim`s together** (`rtrim($number, '0.')`)?

This will cause `10.0000` to become `1` which is obviously incorrect.

**Examples:**

```
$number = 0.000010950000;
```

> output: $number = 0.00001095

and

```
$number = 10.000000;
```

> output: $number = 10