# Laravel Blade Directive for number with 2 or 4 digits

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to make a "dynamic" custom blade directive which fails because it receives the variable name and not the float. (latest laravel version)

I wanted to extend that one:

```
Blade::directive('money', function ($money) {
    return "<?php echo number_format($money, 2, ',', ''); ?>";
});
```

with an if statement `if (str_ends_with($money, "00")) ...` which will of cause not work, what I found out.
Is there any other way to fullfill this task?

12.3400 should be displayed as 12,34

12.3401 should be displayed as 12,3401

if there is no other solution:
for the moment i am using a blade component

```
@props(['money'])

@if (str_ends_with($money, '00'))
    {{ number_format($money, 2, ',', '') }}
@else
    {{ number_format($money, 4, ',', '') }}
@endif
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove useless zero digits from decimals in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531679/remove-useless-zero-digits-from-decimals-in-php)

Comment: What does "it receives the variable name and not the float" mean? You must be calling it incorrectly. Also note `number_format()` should be passed a float, not a string.

Comment: @miken32 i mean if you want to use `$money` outside the returned php echo you only have the variable name as string. Try to `dd($money);` , it will output "$yourVariable", not the actual value of that variable - that was my initial misstake.

Comment: Oh yes you're building a PHP statement, not running PHP commands. Whatever you put in the `@money` directive gets passed literally into to that statement without being evaluated. The assumption is that `$money` is a real variable in the scope of the blade template, so when the template is completely built and then the PHP is evaluated, it will know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing '$money' in str_ends_with() method:

```
  Blade::directive('money', function ($money) {
     return "<?php echo str_ends_with('$money', '00') ? number_format($money, 2, ',', '') : number_format($money, 4, ',', ''); ?>";
  });
```

Comment: thanks, that now did the trick, but I had to remove the single quote in the if statement. I have tried this once, but I think i forgot to clear the views ...